# Is it possible to create a pure PHP Storm Topology?

Tags: php, apache-storm

According to the **Getting Started with Storm** book from O'Reilly:

> There is a way to specify topologies in a non-JVM language. Since Storm topologies are just Thrift structures, and Nimbus is a Thrift daemon, you can create and submit topologies in any language you want. But this it out of the scope of this book.

I know the book is a little outdated, but I'm hoping this tidbit is possible.

Is there a way to submit a pure PHP Storm Topology?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Rationale) it says (as one of the key properties of storm)

> **Programming language agnostic:** Robust and scalable realtime processing
>   shouldn't be limited to a single platform. ***Storm topologies and
>   processing components can be defined in any language***, making Storm
>   accessible to nearly anyone.

You can probably look **[here](https://github.com/lazyshot/storm-php)** for similar things.

Comment: Yes, this shows how bolts and spouts can be developed in PHP, but this still needs to use the Java-based storm topology builder. What I'm looking for is a PHP-based storm topology builder. Can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Lazyshot/storm-php/blob/master/lib/storm.php) is the implementation class sample

Answer (score 0):

Closest documentation of this that I've found:

https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Using-non-JVM-languages-with-Storm

It mentions where to get started. I guess I just have to do more research on this.